# Python's OOP for Calculating Growth of Money

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, mathematics

I am making an OOP to calculate growth of money according to theory of interest. I have made 3 classes: `Contribution` which contain data of a deposit and its growth, `InterestRate`, and `GrowthTL` which means to calculate the accumulated value at the `t_end` of all contributions with applied, may be varying, interest rates. I would like to know if there is better structure to write the code, for efficiency and to make it more user-friendly. Thanks.

```
import random


class Contribution(object):
    def __init__(self, t, amount):
        self.t = t
        self.amount = amount

    def accumulate(self, t_end, interest_rates, sort = True):
        interest_rates = [i for i in interest_rates]
        result = self.amount
        if sort:
            interest_rates = sorted(interest_rates, key = lambda x: x.t)

        while True:
            if len(interest_rates)>1:
                if (interest_rates[0].t <= self.t < interest_rates[0+1].t):
                    break
                else:
                    interest_rates.pop(0)
            elif len(interest_rates)==1:
                if self.t >= interest_rates[0].t:
                    break
                else:
                    interest_rates.pop(0)
            else:
                break
            
        if len(interest_rates)>0:
            t_start = self.t
            for i in range(len(interest_rates)-1):
                power = (interest_rates[i+1].t - t_start)/interest_rates[i].period_length
                if interest_rates[i].discount:
                    result = result*((1-interest_rates[i].rate)**(-power))
                else:
                    if interest_rates[i].compound:
                        result = result*((1+interest_rates[i].rate)**(power))
                    else:
                        result = result*(1+ (power*interest_rates[i].rate))
                t_start = interest_rates[i+1].t

            if interest_rates[-1].discount:
                    result = result*((1-interest_rates[-1].rate)**(-(t_end-t_start)))
            else:
                if interest_rates[-1].compound:
                    result = result*((1+interest_rates[-1].rate)**(t_end-t_start))
                else:
                    result = result*(1+((t_end-t_start)*interest_rates[-1].rate))
        return result
    

class InterestRate(object):
    
    def __init__(self, t, rate, period_desc, compound = True, discount = False):
        self.t = t
        self.rate = rate
        self.period_desc = period_desc
        self.compound = compound
        self.discount = discount
        if self.period_desc == "annual":
            self.period_length = 1
        elif self.period_desc == "semi-annual":
            self.period_length = 1/2
        elif self.period_desc == "quarter":
            self.period_length =  1/4
        elif self.period_desc == "month":
            self.period_length = 1/12
        else:
            self.period_length = self.period_desc


class GrowthTL(object):

    def __init__(self, interval, contributions, interest_rates):
        self.interval = interval
        self.t_start = self.interval[0]
        self.t_end = self.interval[1]

        self.contributions = sorted(contributions, key = lambda x: x.t)
        contributions = []; t_taken = []
        for i in range(len(self.contributions)):
            if i not in t_taken:
                contributions.append( self.contributions[i] )
                t_taken.append(i)
        self.contributions = contributions
        
        self.interest_rates = sorted(interest_rates, key = lambda x: x.t)
        int_rates = []; t_taken = []
        for i in range(len(self.interest_rates)):
            if i not in t_taken:
                int_rates.append( self.interest_rates[i] )
                t_taken.append(i)
        self.interest_rates = int_rates
        if self.t_start not in t_taken:
            self.interest_rates[0].t = self.t_start
        
    def value_at_end(self):
        results = []
        for c in contributions:
            result = c.accumulate(self.t_end, self.interest_rates, sort = False)
            results.append(result)
            print(result)
        return sum(results)    



amount = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
t_amount = [1, 2, 3, 14, 15]
int_rate = [0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.04, 0.05, 0.2]
t_int_rate = [0, 2, 3, 4, 4.5, 10]

periods = ["annual", "semi-annual", "quarter", "month"]

contributions = [Contribution(t_amount[i], amount[i]) for i in range(len(amount))]
int_rates = [InterestRate(t_int_rate[i], int_rate[i], random.sample(periods, 1)[0]) for i in range(len(int_rate))]
obj = GrowthTL([0, 20], contributions, int_rates)

print(obj.value_at_end())
```

Answer (score 2):

### Little things

```
class Contribution(object):
```

object is the implied parent of all classes. This can be written as `class Contribution:`.

```
amount = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
t_amount = [1, 2, 3, 14, 15]
int_rate = [0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.04, 0.05, 0.2]
t_int_rate = [0, 2, 3, 4, 4.5, 10]
```

Having separate variables for time values and monetary / fractional values seems odd. The data would be reflected more accurately in your code if it were phrased together.

```
contributions_data = [
    (1,100),
    (2,200),
    (3,300),
    (14,400),
    (15,500)
]
contributions = [
    Contribution(t, amount) 
    for t,amount in contributions_data
]
```

The constructor is a very important method, so it should be left as simple as possible.

```
class InterestRate:
    periods = {
        'annual':1,
        'semi-annual':1/2,
        'quarter':1/4,
        'month':1/12
    }
    @staticmethod
    def get_period_length(period):
        if period in InterestRate.periods:
            return InterestRate.periods[period]
        return period
    
    def __init__(self, t, rate, period_desc, compound = True, discount = False):
        self.t = t
        self.rate = rate
        self.compound = compound
        self.discount = discount
        
        self.period_length = InterestRate.get_period_length(period_desc)
```

### Big Things

`accumulate()` has an insane amount of responsibility. The specific rules for applying interest rates should be moved elsewhere.

```
class InterestRate:
    def apply(self,amount,delta):
        power = delta/self.period_length
        if self.discount:
            return amount*((1-self.rate)**(-power))
        if self.compound:
            return amount*((1+self.rate)**power)

        return amount*(1+(power*self.rate))

class Contribution:
    def rate_applies(self,interest_rate,t_end):
        return t_end >= interest_rate.t >= self.t
    def accumulate(self, t_end, interest_rates, sort = True):
        interest_rates = interest_rates[:]
        if sort:
            interest_rates = sorted(interest_rates, key = lambda x: x.t)

        applicable_rates = [
            rate for rate in interest_rates 
            if self.rate_applies(rate,t_end)
        ]

        with_interest = self.amount
        for i in range(len(applicable_rates)-1):
            delta = applicable_rates[i+1].t - max(self.t,applicable_rates[i].t)
            with_interest = applicable_rates[i].apply(with_interest,delta)
   
        if len(applicable_rates)>0:
            delta = t_end - applicable_rates[-1].t
            with_interest = applicable_rates[-1].apply(with_interest,delta)

        return with_interest
```

Both `GrowthTL` and `Contribution` seem to be worried about selecting the valid interest for the timespan. Since `Contribution` already handles interest rate validation, `GrowthTL` can be simplified.

```
class GrowthTL:

    def __init__(self, interval, contributions, interest_rates):
        self.t_start,self.t_end = interval

        self.contributions = sorted(contributions, key = lambda x: x.t)
        self.interest_rates = sorted(interest_rates, key = lambda x: x.t)
        
    def value_at_end(self):
        return sum([
            contribution.accumulate(self.t_end, self.interest_rates, sort = False)
            for contribution in self.contributions
        ])
```